# Does $|\kappa^{<\kappa}|=|\lambda^{<\lambda}|$ imply $\kappa=\lambda$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

For sets $A,B$ we write $A\approx B$ if there is a bijection between $S$ sand $B$.

If $\kappa$ is a cardinal, let $\kappa^{<\kappa}$ denote the collection of subsets of $\kappa$ having cardinality $<\kappa$.

If $\kappa,\lambda$ are cardinals, does $\kappa^{<\kappa} \approx \lambda^{<\lambda}$ imply $\kappa=\lambda$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Consider when $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_2}=\aleph_3$, with $\kappa=\aleph_1$ and $\lambda=\aleph_2$.

---

If you allow for one of these to be singular, then consider $\kappa=\beth_\omega$ and $\lambda=\kappa^+$. Then $\lambda^{<\lambda}=\lambda^\kappa=2^\kappa\cdot\lambda$, and on the other hand since $\kappa$ is a strong limit cardinal, $\kappa^{<\kappa}=2^\kappa$ as well.

If, on the other hand, you require that both are regular, then there is no provable counterexample, since $\sf GCH$ implies that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$ for all regular cardinals.

Comment: Are you assuming $\lnot$CH?

Comment: It literally says $2^{\aleph_0}=\dots=\aleph_3$, so yes, this assumes that CH fails.

Comment: Yes, but how can you miss the opportunity of raising you hand and pointing it out with a shiny comment?